# Default url for all product listings in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to access the root category url or in other words default url for all product listing in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

In Block

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class A
{
    public $registry;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry) 
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }


    public function getCurrentlyCategoryPath()
    {
       $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
       return $category->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was expecting it without any code. For example the category page url is **http://domainname.com/men.html** similarly I wants to access the default product listing on the category page even without creating any parent category. 

Is it possible or what is the best way to achieve it.